# Use XML parser for non-xml file?

Tags: xml, regex, perl

I have a bunch of LTE CDR's that when decoded look and feel just like XML, but aren't (I'm not sure the exact differences, but it's hierarchical, similar to XML). I've copied one of the lines below. There are 50 or 60 entries just like this in each file.

My goal is to search for an entry that matches and IP address (below in HEX) and time range. Then to correlate the IMSI to it. These field are below.

Fields I'm searching for:

```
...
<servedIMSI>13 91 03 00 00 00 10 F8</servedIMSI>
...
<servedPDPAddress>
        <iPAddress>
            <iPBinaryAddress>
                <iPBinV4Address>0A 37 00 11</iPBinV4Address>
            </iPBinaryAddress>
        </iPAddress>
    </servedPDPAddress>
...
<timeOfFirstUsage>14 02 04 04 09 40 2D 06 00</timeOfFirstUsage>
<timeOfLastUsage>14 02 04 04 12 44 2D 06 00</timeOfLastUsage>
...
```

I've tried to use XML tools, but since this is not XML, they don't work.

I was wondering if there is a better way to search and retrieve the data I want. I can use regex expressions to find the data, but the XML approach seems to be a better approach (even though this isn't XML). I'm open to any and all ideas!

Snippet of CDR:

```
<GPRSRecord>
    <egsnPDPRecord>
        <recordType>70</recordType>
        <servedIMSI>13 91 03 00 00 00 10 F8</servedIMSI>
        <ggsnAddress>
            <iPBinaryAddress>
                <iPBinV4Address>AB CD 72 62</iPBinV4Address>
            </iPBinaryAddress>
        </ggsnAddress>
        <chargingID>126400647</chargingID>
        <sgsnAddress>
                <iPBinaryAddress>
                    <iPBinV4Address>AB CD 72 62</iPBinV4Address>
                </iPBinaryAddress>

        </sgsnAddress>
        <accessPointNameNI><bs/>Internet<si/>syringawireless<etx/>com</accessPointNameNI>
        <pdpType>01 21</pdpType>
        <servedPDPAddress>
            <iPAddress>
                <iPBinaryAddress>
                    <iPBinV4Address>0A 37 00 11</iPBinV4Address>
                </iPBinaryAddress>
            </iPAddress>
        </servedPDPAddress>
        <dynamicAddressFlag><true/></dynamicAddressFlag>
        <listOfTrafficVolumes>
            <ChangeOfCharCondition>
                <dataVolumeGPRSUplink>192323</dataVolumeGPRSUplink>
                <dataVolumeGPRSDownlink>320043</dataVolumeGPRSDownlink>
                <changeCondition><recordClosure/></changeCondition>
                <changeTime>14 02 04 04 12 46 2D 06 00</changeTime>
                <userLocationInformation>01 13 01 39 01 86 BD 01</userLocationInformation>
            </ChangeOfCharCondition>
        </listOfTrafficVolumes>
        <recordOpeningTime>14 02 04 04 09 40 2D 06 00</recordOpeningTime>
        <duration>186</duration>
        <causeForRecClosing>16</causeForRecClosing>
        <recordSequenceNumber>26784</recordSequenceNumber>
        <nodeID>1</nodeID>
        <localSequenceNumber>8858562</localSequenceNumber>
        <apnSelectionMode><mSorNetworkProvidedSubscriptionVerified/></apnSelectionMode>
        <servedMSISDN>91 02 98 99 00 81</servedMSISDN>
        <chargingCharacteristics>01 00</chargingCharacteristics>
        <chChSelectionMode><sGSNSupplied/></chChSelectionMode>
        <sgsnPLMNIdentifier>13 01 39</sgsnPLMNIdentifier>
        <servedIMEISV>53 97 04 40 81 57 80 00</servedIMEISV>
        <rATType>6</rATType>
        <userLocationInformation>01 13 01 39 01 86 BD 01</userLocationInformation>
        <listOfServiceData>
            <ChangeOfServiceCondition>
                <ratingGroup>1</ratingGroup>
                <localSequenceNumber>1</localSequenceNumber>
                <timeOfFirstUsage>14 02 04 04 09 40 2D 06 00</timeOfFirstUsage>
                <timeOfLastUsage>14 02 04 04 12 44 2D 06 00</timeOfLastUsage>
                <serviceConditionChange>
                    00000000000000000000000010000000
                </serviceConditionChange>
                <sgsn-Address>
                    <iPBinaryAddress>
                        <iPBinV4Address>AB CD 72 62</iPBinV4Address>
                    </iPBinaryAddress>
                </sgsn-Address>
                <sGSNPLMNIdentifier>13 01 39</sGSNPLMNIdentifier>
                <datavolumeFBCUplink>192323</datavolumeFBCUplink>
                <datavolumeFBCDownlink>320043</datavolumeFBCDownlink>
                <timeOfReport>14 02 04 04 12 46 2D 06 00</timeOfReport>
                <rATType>6</rATType>
                <userLocationInformation>01 13 01 39 01 86 BD 01</userLocationInformation>
            </ChangeOfServiceCondition>
        </listOfServiceData>
    </egsnPDPRecord>
</GPRSRecord>
```

Comment: Please give a specific programming problem, not asking for approaches - this is too broad, and can easily be off-topic. Please take a [tour].

Comment: I can see nothing in that data that doesn't comply with the XML standard. Certainly the second sample - beginning `<GPRSRecord>` - is valid XML as my XML editor tells me so. Please show the code that you have used, and a complete data file - edited if necessary to make it a manageable size - that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Unihedron I don't think the question is too broad. The core of the question is, "How can I use a Perl XML parser to parse the following file?"

Comment: What you posted is valid XML. Some "high-level" parsers won't be able to deal with `<accessPointNameNI><bs/>Internet<si/>syringawireless<etx/>com</accessPointNameNI>` (text and non-text child nodes), but XML::LibXML can. ("High-level" XML parsers exist to make things simpler, but they invariably make them more complicated.)

Comment: when you try to parse you real data, using `xmlwf` or `xmllint`, whats the error message you get? If you can fix the errors and make your data XML, then you can use XML tools.

Comment: It definitely is XML. You say "I've tried to use XML tools, but since this is not XML, they don't work.". How exactly do they not work? What is the error you get?

Comment: Wait, are you saying the file contains `13 91 03 00 00 00 10 F8` or the characters the 8 bytes the hex represents. The latter wouldn't be valid XML. If that's what you have, I recommend writing your own parser. XML has a very simple syntax if you don't have to support directives, entities other than character entities and namespaces.

Answer (score 4):

XML parsers exist to parse well-formed XML. They will typically fail - often messily - if your XML is *not* well-formed.

Your XML seems to be well-formed though. So personally, I'd start with using `XML::Twig` as a personal favourite.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub extractIMSI {
    my ( $twig, $servedIMSI ) = @_;
    print $servedIMSI -> text(),"\n";
    $twig -> purge(); #why I like XML::Twig - it lets you clear memory on the fly
}

my $parser = XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { 'servedIMSI' => \&extractIMSI } );

$parser -> parsefile ( 'test.xml' );
```

Works if the 'test.xml' contains your sample data, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This short Perl program processes a file called `GPRSRecord.xml`, which contains the data you show in your question, wrapped in a `<root>...</root>` element. It extracts the fields that you say you're interested in from every `egsnPDPRecord` element that it finds. Clearly, in this case there is only one.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'GPRSRecord.xml');

for my $pdp_rec ($xml->findnodes('/root/GPRSRecord/egsnPDPRecord')) {

  my ($imsi_address) = $pdp_rec->findnodes('servedIMSI');
  printf "%s: %s\n", $imsi_address->nodeName, $imsi_address->textContent;

  my ($ip_v4_address) = $pdp_rec->findnodes('servedPDPAddress/iPAddress/iPBinaryAddress/iPBinV4Address');
  printf "%s: %s\n", $ip_v4_address->nodeName, $ip_v4_address->textContent;

  my ($service_condition) = $pdp_rec->findnodes('listOfServiceData/ChangeOfServiceCondition');
  my ($first_usage)       = $service_condition->findnodes('timeOfFirstUsage');
  my ($last_usage)        = $service_condition->findnodes('timeOfLastUsage');
  printf "%s: %s\n", $first_usage->nodeName, $first_usage->textContent;
  printf "%s: %s\n", $last_usage->nodeName, $last_usage->textContent;

}
```

**output**

```
servedIMSI: 13 91 03 00 00 00 10 F8
iPBinV4Address: 0A 37 00 11
timeOfFirstUsage: 14 02 04 04 09 40 2D 06 00
timeOfLastUsage: 14 02 04 04 12 44 2D 06 00
```

Answer (score 1):

A stateful loop in Perl could work pretty easily, with the caveat that much of the work done by an XML parser to handle multi-line entries, etc., would need to be duplicated here for any files that do not match the example text.  Something like

```
my $infile;
open($infile, "MyCDRFile.nxm");

my %searches = {
  "rec_start" => "egsnPDPRecord",
  "imsi" => "servedIMSI",
  "ip" => "iPBinV4Address",
  "firsttime" => "timeOfFirstUsage",
  "lasttime" => "timeOfLastUsage"
};
my %finds;
my ($imsi,) = ("");

while (my $line = <$infile>) {
  chomp($line);

  if (index($line, $searches{"rec_start"}) > -1) {
    if ($imsi ne "") print "[$imsi, " + join(',', @finds{"ip", "firsttime", "lasttime"}) + "]\n";
    $imsi = "";
  }
  if (index($line, $searches{"imsi"}) > -1) {
    $imsi = (split($line, $searches{"imsi"}))[1];
    $imsi =~ s![<>/]!!g;
  }
  foreach my $search ("ip", "firsttime", "lasttime") {
    if ($imsi ne "" and index($line, $searches{$search}) > -1) {
      $finds{$search} = (split($line, $searches{$search}))[1];
      $finds{$search} =~ s![<>/]!!g;
    }
  }
}

close($infile);
```

Printing out to a separate file, reading from `STDIN`, etc. could all be added into this fairly easily.